# Where did this statistics formula come from: $E[X^2] = \mu^2 + \sigma^2$

Tags: statistics

I am studying statistics and I need some guidance as to where this formula came from. All I know is that $\displaystyle E[X^2] = x^2 \sum_{i=0}^n p_{i}(x)$

Comment: The definition of $\sigma^2$ (namely $\sigma^2 = E[(X - \mu)^2]$) boils down to $\sigma^2 = E[X^2] - \mu^2$.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I see it now. I should really study those identities.

Comment: There is a different way to look at the proof  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3618238/1108681

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $X$ be a real valued random variable, $\mu = E[X]$ its mean, and $\sigma^2 = E[(X-E[X])^2]$ its variance. Then,
\begin{align}\sigma^2 & = E[(X-E[X])^2] \\ & = E[X^2 - 2XE[X]+(E[X])^2] \\ & = E[X^2] - E[2XE[X]]+E[(E[X])^2] \\ & = E[X^2] - 2(E[X])^2+(E[X])^2 \\ & =  E[X^2] - (E[X])^2 \\ & = E[X^2] - \mu^2.\end{align}
This gives us $E[X^2] = \sigma^2+\mu^2$.
Which Proves your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Thanks to the Did's comment and as a alternative answer.

You can use the following definition:

If $X$ is any random variable with distribution $F_{X}(x)$, then

$$\mu_{X}=\int \limits_{0}^{+\infty}\left({1-F_{X}(x)}\right)dx-\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}F_{X}(x)dx,$$

$$\sigma_{X}^{2}=\int \limits_{0}^{+\infty} 2x \left( {1-F_{X}(x)+F_{X}(-x) } \right)dx-\mu_{X}^2$$

and then show that

$$E[X^2]=\int \limits_{0}^{+\infty} 2x \left( {1-F_{X}(x)+F_{X}(-x) } \right)dx$$

to conclude your equality.

Comment: And if X is neither discrete nor continuous?

Comment: The question seems like for discrete random variable. However I tried improve my answer.